# Regular values of $g(x,y)= x^2 - y^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-verification, manifolds

I am doing some very introductory studying about manifolds. I wanted to check I was getting the right end of the stick through this example. Could anyone verify/correct my solution to the following question;

**Question:** Find all the regular value of the map $g : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by: $g(x,y) = x^2 - y^2$

**My Answer:** Well, $dg(x,y) = [2x,  -2y]$, and, in order for $z \in \mathbb{R}$ to be a regular value of $g$ we need that for every $(x,y) \in g^{-1} (z)$ for rank  $dg(x,y) =1$. So in this case we just need  rank  $dg(x,y) \neq 0$, i.e. $(0,0) \notin g^{-1}(z)$. So since $g(0,0) =0$ we have that $0$ is *not* a regular value of $g$ and every $z \in \mathbb{R} - \{0\}$  *is* a regular value of $g$.

Any advice here would be appreciated as I am finding things a little confusing.

Comment: I think $z<0$ is a value of $g$, specifically $g(0,\sqrt{-z}) = z$. perhaps you thought $g$ was $g(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ rather than $g(x,y) = x^2 -y^2$?

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Comment: Though, I did do that exact exercise ( with $g(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$) and fell into that very trap you pointed out, so thank you!

Comment: Still it's worth looking, what the regular value theorem tells you out of your observations: For $z \neq 0$ the inverse image of $z$ under $g$ is some hyperbola (which is a manifold of codimension 1), but for $z=0$ it's the union of 2 straight lines, namley $y=x$ and $y=-x$, which s obviously not a manifold.